# Get all child notes only one level lower from parent object in Appium (Android)

Tags: java, android, listview, xpath, appium

I write an automation testing software and have one problem now.
In my actual **native app** I have a ListView like this here:

- ListView

  - *LinearLayout*

    - LinearLayout

      - LinearLayout
    - TextView
  - *LinearLayout*

    - LinearLayout
  - *LinearLayout*

    - LinearLayout
  - *LinearLayout*
  - ...

... and more.

What I need and want is to get all one level lower **LinearLayout** (iterative ones, visible and non visible elements) from **ListView**:

ListView : {LinearLayout, LinearLayout, ...}

With that code I get all childs from ListView, but its to much for me:

```
listViewChildElements       = "[...]android.widget.ListView[1]//android.widget.LinearLayout";
app.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(listViewChildElements));
```

In another post I see something with 'count', but I don't understand it.

Thanks for your help and nice to meet you.

---

With the help of @har07 I write one function, not best or finest solution and not finally, but the 1st step in the right lane:

```
    public static List<String> getAllViewElements(App app){
    int i = 0;

    List<String> writtenElementsByText = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(true){
        if(!writtenElementsByText.isEmpty()){
            String recentLastItem = writtenElementsByText.get(writtenElementsByText.size()-1);
            if(recentLastItem.equals("Alle Themen"))
                break;
            else
                app.getDriver().scrollTo(recentLastItem);
        }

        List<WebElement> tmp = app.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(listViewChildElements));


        if(writtenElementsByText.isEmpty())
            for(WebElement e: tmp){
                writtenElementsByText.add(getTextFromElement(e));
            }
        else
            for(WebElement e: tmp){
                String activualElemenByText = getTextFromElement(e);
                if(!writtenElementsByText.contains(activualElemenByText))
                    writtenElementsByText.add(activualElemenByText);
            }
    }

    System.out.println(writtenElementsByText.size());
    for(String e: writtenElementsByText){
        System.out.println("\t-\t"+e);
    }
    return writtenElementsByText;
}

public static String getTextFromElement(WebElement element){
    return element.findElement(By.id(listViewChildElementTextID)).getText();
}
```

Comment: do you want to access all the `LinearLayout` within your `ListView`?

Comment: Yes, everyone - visible and not visible, and only one level lower from ListView. I edit my post and add this information (native app too)

Comment: The tip of @har07 help to find a solution. I written a new function which u can see under my starting post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to use single slash (`/`) instead of double to get direct child element from a parent element :

```
listViewChildElements = "[...]android.widget.ListView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout";
                                                        ^
                                                        notice that only one slash being 
                                                        used above
```

With that change, the XPath should now return `LinearLayout` that is direct child of the `ListView[1]`.

Comment: I written a new function and this give me all direct childs. But now i have another problem: with `driver.scrollTo(NAME)`.
Has ScrollTo function problem with `,` or to long parts in `NAME`?

Comment: that should probably be a separate question

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following piece of code helps :

```
 WebElement listViewElement = driver.findElement(<your ListView locator>);
 List<WebElement> listLinearLayoutChildren = listViewElement.findElements(By.className("android.widget.LinearLayout")); //All the linear layouts under ListView in one list
 listLinearLayoutChildren.get(index).<action>; //index of Nth linearlayout starting from 0 and <action> you want to perform
```

Comment: Give it from your solution anyway to delete all other linearLayouts their are not direct childs from ListView?

Comment: @ShiroEmiya : couldn't get you there

Comment: I write a new function (see in op). But i have a new problem, which can you see under the commentary of @har07

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to do by setting Tag to each `linearLayout`.
Now access linearlayout by `view.findViewWithTag(index)`