# Click on a child element in appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

In my app I need to click on a child element and for some reason its not working.

This is the parent element:

```
WebElement element = device.getDriverWrapper().getIosDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[4]"));
```

This element contains textview and a lock. I need to press on the lock.

This is the child element:

```
WebElement child = element.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAButton[1]"));
child.click();
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

thanks

Comment: Do you need the parent element? Is there a reason you don't just use "//UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[4]/UIAButton[1]" ?

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699528/1746118), I would suggest a modification as :

```
WebElement child = element.findElement(By.xpath("/UIAButton[1]"));
```

Should help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the xpath for child element from `"//UIAButton[1]"` to `".//UIAButton[1]"`.

The xpath starts with `"."` means finding element under the parent. If not, it means finding element under the root.